# Where's the HXML docs?

Tags: command-line, actionscript-2, haxe, swf-compiler, hxml

I've looked all over the [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) Flash Command-line compiler website but was unable to find any detailed **documentation of the [HXML files](http://haxe.org/doc/start/flash)** *(scroll down to the "Changing SWF properties" section)* which describe the compile.

Anybody know of a reference [source?](http://haxe.org/wiki/search?s=HXML)

---

Found HXML:

- **-swf** MyApp.swf .... *Compile to SWF*
- **-main** MyAppClass .... *Entry-point Class (.AS file)*
- **-swf-header** 200:300:25:FFFFFF .... *Width:Height:FPS:BackColor (of SWF)*

---

**Edit:**  Scroll down for my answer with the **complete list** of commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
haxe --help
```

.hxml files are just a convenient way to pass commandline parameters as far as I know.

Comment: Is there any difference between the syntax of the command line parameters and the syntax of an .hxml file?

Comment: I think that the `.hxml`’s support for comments is something that the commandline parser doesn’t support. E.g., I get an error if I try to pass `"comment"` to `haxe` but I can write that in `.hxml` just fine.

Answer (score 10):

Got it! Here's the complete list of HXML / command line **Options** for the Haxe compiler

- —cp  : add a directory to find source files
- —js  : compile code to JavaScript file
- —as3  : generate AS3 code into target directory
- —swf  : compile code to Flash SWF file
- —swf9  : compile code to Flash9 SWF file
- —swf—version  : change the SWF version (6 to 10)
- —swf—header  : define SWF header (width:height:fps:color)
- —swf—lib  : add the SWF library to the compiled SWF
- —neko  : compile code to Neko Binary
- —php  : generate PHP code into target directory
- —x  : shortcut for compiling and executing a neko file
- —xml  : generate XML types description
- —main  : select startup class
- —lib  : use an haxelib library
- —D  : define a conditional compilation flag
- —resource [@name] : add a named resource file
- —exclude  : don’t generate code for classes listed in this file
- —v : turn on verbose node
- —debug : add debug informations to the compiled code
- —prompt : prompt on error
- —cmd : run the specified command after successful compilation
- ——flash—strict : more type strict flash API
- ——no—traces : don’t compile trace calls in the program
- ——flash—use—stage : place objects found on the stage of the SWF lib
- ——neko—source : keep generated neko source
- ——gen—hx—classes  : generate hx headers from SWF9 file
- ——next : separate several haxe compilations
- ——display : display code tips
- ——no—output : compiles but does not generate any file
- ——times : measure compilation times
- —-no—inline : disable inlining
- ——php—front  : select the name for the PHP front file
- ——remap  : remap a package to another one
- —help : Display this list of options
- ——help : Display this list of options

Answer (score 2):

For an **advanced usage** and some tips here is a great article by Andy Li (https://stackoverflow.com/users/267998/andy-li)

http://blog.onthewings.net/2013/03/04/hxml-tricks-every-haxe-user-should-know/

---

## Commenting a hxml file

Lines starting with hash (#) won't be treated as arguments.

```
#Yay! Comments!
```

## Run project right after compilation

Use `-cmd` to run any command line after successful compilation.

```
#C++
-cpp bin
-main Test
-cmd ./bin/Test

#Flash
-swf Test.swf  
-main Test  
-cmd path/to/FlashDebugger Test.swf

#Neko
-neko Test.n  
-main Test  
-cmd neko Test.n
```

For Neko target there is special shortcut for building and running `-x Test`.

## Extra arguments

Appending arguments also works, for example if you want to build debug version

```
haxe project.hxml -debug
```

## Multiple compilations at once

Use `--next` to separate different target/configuration builds. Use `--each` to apply arguments to every build within hxml.

```
#lib will be used in every '--next' build
-lib jQueryExtern  
--each  

#build MainPage
-js script/MainPage.js  
-main MainPage  
--next  

#build ContactPage
-js script/ContactPage.js  
-main ContactPage  

#build AlbumPage
--next  
-js script/AlbumPage.js  
-main AlbumPage
```

## Including hxmls

You can further separate different build configurations by creating an hxml for every configuration.

client.hxml:

```
-main Client
-js client.js
```

server.hxml:

```
-main Server
-neko server.n
```

all.hxml:

```
client.hxml
--next
server.hxml
```

Builds both: `haxe all.hxml`